# Jquery , load() does not work when specific button is clicked

Tags: jquery

Hello there is my problem:

I do a chat and I want message to be added in database after clicking a button.

Heres a code:

```
   $('button[id="czat_pisz"]').bind('click',function() {
       alert("Passes");
       $('#hidden').load("czat_pisanie.php?type=" + chat_type + "?message=" + text + "?nick=" + gracz_nick);
  });
```

The alert is just for check. It is showing when I click a button. But the load() does not work. It works when I put it out from click function.

How to fix it?

Comment: You have an invalid URL for most servers. You should not have more than one "?". And I hope your parameter values are already encoded...

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid url

```
$('#hidden').load("czat_pisanie.php?type=" + chat_type + "?message=" + text + "?nick=" + gracz_nick);
```

use this

```
$('#hidden').load("czat_pisanie.php?type=" + chat_type + "&message=" + text + "&nick=" + gracz_nick);
```

Comment: No; `load()` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for misunderstanding

```
 $('#hidden').load("czat_pisanie.php?type=" + chat_type + "?message=" + text + "?nick=" + gracz_nick);
```

here is the probelem

should be

```
 $('#hidden').load("czat_pisanie.php?type="+chat_type+"&message="+text +"&nick="+ gracz_nick);
```

according to your comment

```
$('button[id="czat_pisz"]').bind('click',function() { > $('#hidden').load("test.html"); }); 
             here is the problem ---------------------^----remove this stray >
```

Comment: @undefined sorry i was mistaken, load() function is deprecatedso so  i thought OP is talking about that load

Comment: @NullPointer load event is deprecateed not the `load()`

Comment: Ok Ive changed it for something easy for now. But still doesnt work.

>    $('button[id="czat_pisz"]').bind('click',function() {
>       $('#hidden').load("test.html");    });

The test.html content is:

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("passed");
    });
    </script>

If I load it without the button click check (only when document is loaded) I see this alert.